# Use all cores to train ANN via neuralnet

Tags: r, neural-network

I am training ANN via package neuralnet in R and the problem is that it uses only 1 core in the training process. 
I've installed package parallel and I've tried to use something like

```
nn<-doParallel|parallel and so...(neuralnet(formula,.....)
```

but I am not wel skilled in these issues.
Any advices to how to let all the cores work during the training process to make it faster?
If I use

```
detectCores()
```

It sees all 4 cores.

Comment: I realize this is pretty old, but if you're still around and looking for a solution, you might find it here http://www.r-bloggers.com/grnn-and-pnn/

I'm very interested in this subject and have been trying to figure it out as well, to no avail. good luck!

Comment: Refer to my code here to see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861114/r-neuralnet-package-too-slow-for-millions-of-records